# HighCharts overlapping column

Tags: highcharts

I have overlapping issue with series in HighCharts column view.

How to solve the overlapping and make every series column separated from each other at same x label?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLRHh/3/

I used `tickPositioner`, not sure if it affects something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange)

```
plotOptions:{
    column:{
        pointRange:1000000000
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XLRHh/4/

Comment: Thank you! Is it approximately one month for the range?

Comment: Almost, one month is 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000